# Create form questions according to answer in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Forms for our Sales colleagues, which allows them to choose their name, the country they are responsible for and then answer a few questions (these questions are always the same).

The name list and the associated countries are saved in a spreadsheet. I use this list to fill the ListItem for the names, and the country list ListItem for every colleague.

At the moment I have a welcome page with two ListItems: Name and Product.
After selecting a name and clicking on "Continue" the form jumps to the corresponding page, where the country ListItem is already prefilled with the countries.

My problem is, that this way I alway have a really long form, although the user sees only two pages. Moreover, the assigned sheet has a separate column for every question.

Would it be possible to generate the second page "on-the-fly" based on the selected name?

UPDATE:

This is my createFrom fuction. It would be nice to generate the questionBlock "on-demand" by passing the selected name or at least set the generated questions to save the response to the same column in the spreadsheet.

```
function createForm() {

  //Names
  var Names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
  var fullNames = ['Mr. Z A', 'Mr. Y B', 'Mr. X C', 'Ms. W D', 'Mr. V E', 'Ms. U F', 'Mr. T G', 'Mr. S H', 'Mr. R I', 'Mr. Q J'];
  var Products = ['Product 1', 'Product 2'];
  var questionBlock = {};

  var form = FormApp.create('Vertriebsländer und Zulassungsplan 2015');

  //Page 1
  form.setTitle('formTitle')
  .setDescription('Please fill out the following survey.');
  form.hasRespondAgainLink();
  form.canEditResponse();

  var lName = form.addListItem()
  .setTitle('Please choose your name:')
  .setRequired(true);

  var choicesName = lName.getChoices();
  choicesName = [];

  var lProduct = form.addListItem()
  .setChoiceValues(Products)
  .setTitle('Please choose the product:')
  .setRequired(true);

//Question Block Page
  for( a = 0; a < Names.length; a++){
      choicesName.push(
        lName.createChoice(fullNames[a],
                       form.addPageBreakItem()
                       .setTitle('Welcome ' + fullNames[a] +'!')
                       .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT)));

questionBlock[ ('lCountries' + Names[a]) ] = form.addListItem();
   questionBlock[ ('lCountries' + Names[a]) ].setTitle('Please choose a country:');
   questionBlock[ ('lCountries' + Names[a]) ].setRequired(true);

questionBlock[('txtQuestion1')] = form.addTextItem();
   questionBlock[('txtQuestion1')].setTitle('Common Question 1');
   questionBlock[('txtQuestion1')].setRequired(true);

questionBlock[('lQuestion2')] = form.addListItem();
   questionBlock[('lQuestion2')].setTitle('Question2');
   questionBlock[('lQuestion2')].setChoiceValues(['A', 'B', 'C']);
   questionBlock[('lQuestion2')].setRequired(true);

questionBlock[('lQuestion3')] = form.addListItem();
   questionBlock[('lQuestion3')].setTitle('Question3');
   questionBlock[('lQuestion3')].setChoiceValues(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']);
   questionBlock[('lQuestion3')].setRequired(true);

questionBlock[('txtQuestion4')] = form.addTextItem();
   questionBlock[('txtQuestion4')].setTitle('Do you have any remarks?');
   questionBlock[('txtQuestion4')].setRequired(false);
  }

  lName.setChoices(choicesName);

  //Fill country selection dropdown==================

  //Spreadsheet
  var ssCountries = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890');
  //Importing data from spreadsheet
  var dataRange = ssCountries.getDataRange(); 
  var values = dataRange.getValues();


  for (i = 0; i < Names.length; i++)
  {
    choices = questionBlock[ ('lCountries' + Names[i]) ].getChoices();
    choices = [];
    for (j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++)
   {
      var curr_name = values[0][j];
     if (curr_name == Names[i])
      {
        for (k = 1; k < values.length; k++)
        {
          if (values[k][j].toString().length > 0)
          {          
            choices.push(questionBlock[ ('lCountries' + Names[i]) ].createChoice(values[k][j]));
            questionBlock[ ('lCountries' + Names[i]) ].setChoices(choices);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //Country selection dropdown filled==================
}
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have worked on.

Comment: I've edited the initial queston to include the source code. I think of using getItemResponds, but I couldn't really figure it out how to debug it, as it is always empty at the time of debugging. (But maybe I just don't understand this whole getResponses thing)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can edit the current open form, and display or hide questions.  You can do that in HTML of course, but I don't think you can do that in a Google Form.  You can edit a current form from code, but then you'd need to save it, close the form, the have the user re-open it I assume.

According to the documentation, you can have a sidebar for a Form.

[Google Documentation - custom sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)

So, you could display a custom sidebar, and show or hide fields using HTML based on a response from the user.  So, what I'm suggesting is, that you wouldn't have a custom second page in your form, you'd have a custom sidebar that dynamically changed based on the users input.

Comment: Is this still undoable in google form?